how to enable fts5 in sqflite in flutter?
Using sqflte to create fts5 table,I got an error:DatabaseException(no such module: fts5 (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR)) .
On website, I got some solution,like adding dependency sqlite3_flutter_libs: ^0.5.4 do not work.

No, Sqlite fts5 Full-text-search is not supported either native android or flutter there was a no such benefits by using fts5 you can use fts4 as always.

Is it support on iOS? and is there any place to follow this issue?

It is not available in out of the box in ios, But some libraries might help to achieve this https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift/blob/master/Documentation/FullTextSearch.md#choosing-the-full-text-engine
